# TIBCO - Generate WSDL Dynamically

Tags: wsdl, tibco

I have a WebService that is a service dispacher and it has a Body with the type anyType, so that way I have only one webservice and my client only needs to know the schema to put in the Body for the specific service that he is calling.

Now the problem is that everytime I create a new service or modify an existing one, I need to send the new schema for them. I need a way so I can generate the WSDL with the body replaced with the schema of the desired service, so I don't have to resend the schema everytime it changes.

Thanks in advance!

BTW I'm using Tibco Designer, if it matters :P

Answer (score 0):

Create an XSLT that expects the generic WSDL as an input and takes a path to a schema as a parameter. Use the XSLT to generate the WSDL you want for your consumers.